# Meshing control of NDEigensystem

Tags: finite-element-method, mesh, eigenvalues

I have to solve an Eigenvalue problem originating from the Electrodynamics. It is a 2-D problem with a rectangular region. More specifically, there is a hole on a rectangle made by magnetic material. This problem should be solve by the "NDEigensystem". Due to the irregular region, it can only be solved by the method "PDEDiscretization", such as Finite Element Method; however, it seems that I cannot monitor the mesh which is important to the solution accuracy. For example, I don't know how to check the mesh around the hole, where the mesh should be denser. On the contrary, in "NDSolve" there are much more commands for the mesh so one can easily check the mesh quality of the solution region.

So I would like to know is it possible to apply the meshing command such as "ToElementMesh" in "NDEigensystem" to control the mesh quality? Thank you.

===========================================================================

EDIT

Thank you for your help. It works. Additional question: For a 1D Eigenvalue problem with the interval composed of different materials, is it necessary to assign the positions of the interface points? (According to the suggestions, these contents have been posted elsewhere. [Interface points of NDEigensystem](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/195587/interface-points-of-ndeigensystem))

Comment: Yes, that should be possible by adding `Method -> {"FiniteElements", MaxCellMeasure` -> r}` and other sub options. You probably won't find it in the docs `NDEigensystem`  but somewhere in the  in the [Finite Element User Guide](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementOverview.html).

Comment: Thanks. So the docs of NDEigensystem should be improved.

Comment: @OttoSturmGeschütz, no it is documented there. I added a link, have you read that?

Comment: @OttoSturmGeschütz, it's much better to ask a new question in stead of changing an answered question. You'll attract much more people to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation is your friend here. Have a look at

- Last two details items of NDEigensytem ref page
- First example of Options -> Method -> PDEDiscrteization of [`NDEigensystem` ref page](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDEigensystem.html#344876156)

Options are specified exactly the same way as for NDSolve PDEDiscretization. NDEigesystem can take an `ElementMesh` as a region description (exactly like `NDSolve`, `NIntegrate`). For more information on mesh generation, you could look at the documentation of `ToElementMesh` and / or the tutorial on `ElementMesh` generation (search for ElementMesh generation in the help system)

This works:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
NDEigensystem[{-Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}], 
  DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, True]}, 
 u[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] ToElementMesh[Disk[]], 6]
```

Comment: Thank you. This code is helpful and heuristic.